# How to predict/test a trained model in real time(webcam)

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I have a model which I trained for action detection. I saved it and have the .h5 or .hdf5 file with me. I want to see the results real time(webcam). I mean I want the model to predict the action performed which is coming from a live webcam feed. How do I go about it? And I also have to puttext to display the "action" which is being predicted. I didn't find a proper description about on how to go about this. I found a lot of articles for only object detection but I don't want for that. Please help me. Any article/video links/website links regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should focus on one problem at a time. For doing prediction you could: 1) load your saved model, 2) start fetching the frames, one at a time 3) call .predict() on each frame 4) add a label on your frame 5) display the frame with the prediction if you want

Comment: Thank you for detailed and organized answer. I really appreciate it. Any article or website which I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments you could do something like this:

```
# 1) load the model
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')


import cv2

# Open the device at the ID 0
# Use the camera ID based on
# /dev/videoID needed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Check if camera was opened correctly
if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Could not open video device")

# 2) fetch one frame at a time from your camera
while(True):
    
    # frame is a numpy array, that you can predict on 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # 3) obtain the prediction
    # depending on your model, you may have to reshape frame
    prediction = model(frame, training=False)
    # you may need then to process prediction to obtain a label of your data, depending on your model. Probably you'll have to apply an argmax to prediction to obtain a label.
    
    # 4) Adding the label on your frame
    __draw_label(frame, 'Label: {}'.format(prediction), (20,20), (255,0,0))

    # 5) Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow("preview",frame)
   
    #Waits for a user input to quit the application
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The function to add the overlay, comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616857/14774959):

```
def __draw_label(img, text, pos, bg_color):
   font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
   scale = 0.4
   color = (0, 0, 0)
   thickness = cv2.FILLED
   margin = 2
   txt_size = cv2.getTextSize(text, font_face, scale, thickness)

   end_x = pos[0] + txt_size[0][0] + margin
   end_y = pos[1] - txt_size[0][1] - margin

   cv2.rectangle(img, pos, (end_x, end_y), bg_color, thickness)
   cv2.putText(img, text, pos, font_face, scale, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

References:

- OpenCV [tutorial](https://opencv-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/intro.html#capture-live-video) on how to fetch frames from a camera
- How to [load](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize?hl=en) and save a keras model
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616857/14774959) full details on how to add an overlay to your frame

Hope this helps getting you on the right track.

On a side note, if you process only one frame at a time, things could become pretty slow. If this is the case you may think about creating a producer-consumer schema. You could have some queues where you temporary store the frames coming from your camera. You process the frames inside the queues in a parallel way. After that you re-organize your frames to show them on the screen in the right order. This could speed things up.