# Recording the real time face expression detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras

I have coded the face expression detection using `Jupyter notebook`, detecting seven expressions of the face (Anger, Sad, Disgust, Happy, ...) and tried the real-time detection using the camera of my laptop. Now I want to record those expressions detected by the model in the real-time detection and create a figure of the detected expressions over time. First of all, is it possible to do so? If not, what other options do I have? For example, can I record the video taken by the camera and later detect the expressions from the video and make a figure from all the expressions detected over time? Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: yes,  it is possible.  what have you done so far or tried ?

Comment: I have done the real-time face expression detection but for recording those emotions and creating a figure based on the emotions and time I could not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import cv2


all_labels = ["Anger", "Sad", "Disgust", "Happy"]

# load the trained model, or train a model
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')

# Open the camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Or similarly open a saved video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video')

# Check if camera was opened correctly
if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Could not open video device")

# Fetch one frame at a time from your camera in real-time or from the video
i=0
while(True):
    
    # frame is a numpy array, that you can predict on 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Obtain the prediction (you may have to reshape frame according to your model)
    prediction = model(frame, training=False)
    # obtain a label from prediction, depending on your label list
    
    # saving the frame in a different folder depending on label predicted
    if label in all_labels:
        cv2.imwrite('{}/frame_{}.jpg'.format(label, i), frame)

    i = i+1
    #Waits for a user input to quit the application
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I made an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73460043/14774959) to a similar but not identical problem. Maybe you can draw inspiration from that. Also this is a great tutorial for [capturing live videos](https://opencv-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/intro.html#capture-live-video) made by OpenCV.

Comment: It helps but the new update of my project says that we want to plot the predicted values in real-time manner! Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: If you need to predict from a camera stream in real-time just use `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` instead of `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video')`.